# Photo app is unable to handle a photo and shows '1 item' in a summary. How to identify and remove it?

Tags: high-sierra, photos.app

In the iCloude Manage storage dialog, I can see

[image]

However in the photo app, it shows
[image]

Obviously a photo is misclassified as an item. Maybe it is corrupted.

How can I identify this 'Item'?

Comment: actually it shows 50765 in iCloud and 50764 (one less) in Photos

Comment: I think you are confused. Please reread the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had "1 item" like you for a long time now, but I figured out how to find it.

1. On your Mac, create a Smart album
2. Select "Filename" "Does not include" and then list several file formats, like:

   - jpeg
   - jpg
   - png
   - gif
   - heic
   - webp
   - mp4
   - mov
   - m4v
3. Save it

Demo smart album:

[image: Smart album config]

The "1 item" I finally found:

[image: The 1 item]

Comment: Awesome! It turns out I have a WAV file in the photo library.

Answer (score 1):

I used an Investigator app on my iPad and discovered there was a pdf file in there. Then I used the Photos app on my Mac and searched for the term ‘pdf’ and the offending file was revealed. Then I just deleted it.